# Swift. Make all classes final?

Tags: ios, swift, final

My question is about using **final** keyword im Swift code. I know that final helps compiler to compile code faster because of dynamic dispatch. So, if I definitely know that I will not inherit some of my classes, should I make all of them final?

Comment: So, if I definitely know that I will not inherit some of my classes, should I make all of them final? If it's some of them then make some of them only final.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was this protective approach taught by the [iOS Stanford course](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-10-apps-with-swift/id1198467120).

The approach was, define all your APIs `private`. It increases encapsulation. Later if you needed to give away something then remove the privacy.

Because it's bad to do it the other way around ie design something public and then later change it to private.

Similarly here, I think making a class `final` and then later deciding it shouldn't be final is better than making a class non-final, allowing multiple classes to subclass it and then later attempt to revert it back to `final` because of some design decisions.

Comment: "Similarly here, I think making a class final and then later deciding it shouldn't be final is better than making a class non-final, allowing multiple classes to subclass it and then later attempt to revert it back to final because of some design decisions." I think this make sense, thank you!

Comment: Just don't follow this slavishly. You the developer know when an exception would make sense...

Answer (score 2):

You are fine to do so if you are 110% you won't attempt to subclass any of your 'final' classes, as your project won't compile if you do so.

The article below has some great information and should help you decide.

http://blog.human-friendly.com/the-importance-of-being-final

Answer (score 0):

If your app or a framework uses a protocols over inheritance then you can define your class types as finals.

If you prefer to use an inheritance over protocols and your app or framework is tested with a Unit Tests then don't define your class types as finals when they are used for a dependency objects because they will not be able to be mocked.